# Grunt - bundler: failed to load command: scss-lint

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, rubygems

I have bootstrap 4 set up locally and when I ran grunt watch I get the following warning:

```
Running "scsslint:docs" (scsslint) task
Warning: 
bundleExec options set but no Bundler executable found in your PATH.
More info: https://github.com/ahmednuaman/grunt-scss-lint
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

To fix this I ran the following command:

```
sudo gem install bundler -n /usr/local/bin
```

Then I got the following message:

```
Running "scsslint:docs" (scsslint) task
Running scss-lint on docs
>> 1. Please make sure you have ruby installed: `ruby -v`
>> 2. Install the `scss-lint` gem by running:
>> gem update --system && gem install scss-lint
```

So I ran the following commands:

```
sudo gem update --system -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install scss_lint -n /usr/local/bin
```

Now when I run grunt watch I get the following:

```
Running "scsslint:docs" (scsslint) task
Running scss-lint on docs
bundler: failed to load command: scss-lint (/usr/local/bin/scss-lint)
Warning: Task "scsslint:docs" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I am on OSX El Capitan. Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

FYI I had to use the -n /usr/local/bin parameter on the commands because it would give me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is, but `scss-lint` is basically a syntax checker.  I find that if I remove `scss-lint` that TWBS complies.

Try:

```
sudo gem uninstall scss-lint
```

Hopefully there will be a better answer than this, but for now this will get you going.